Switching time of under/over voltage relay
I would like to know what the switching time of the C/O contacts for this relay is (Schneider RM22TR33), i cannot find it in any documentation:


According to the Datasheet, which is easily available online, you can set the time between 0.1 to 40 seconds.
scroll down to downloads

Apologies, I did not word my question correctly (I have edited now). I would like to know the switching time of the two C/O contacts

According to the same Datasheet, the response time is <=300ms. I doubt you'll find a value "C/O contact switching time".

indeed, I noticed this too. I'm guessing the actual switching of the contacts will be in the order of ~10ms?

What is the intention behind the question? Like why would that switching time be relevant in your application? Wanna build a UPS?
